# Proving that $1-x \ge \exp{\frac{-x}{1-x}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to show that
$$1-x \ge e^{\frac{-x}{1-x}}, \quad 0 \le x < 1.$$
I tried to prove the statement above using Lagrange theorem however with no further results.

I would really appreciate any hint or tip.

Comment: $\frac{-x}{1-x}=1-\frac{1}{1-x}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By $1-x=\frac1{1+y}$ with $y\ge 0$ we have

$$1-x \ge e^{\frac{-x}{1-x}} \iff \frac1{1+y} \ge e^{-y} \iff e^{y}\ge 1+y$$